# Update Wordpress shortcode based off name

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I have a custom post type called Fruit and I'm looking to create a shortcode that will update based on what I call the shortcode. For example the custom post type is called fruit and I have a list of fruit as the posts. I want the shortcode to link to that fruits post.

```
add_shortcode('apple', 'apple');
function apple()
{
return '<a href="http://example.com/fruit/apple/>Apple</a>';
}
```

Now I could write a shortcode for orange, bannna and every other fruit but I was wondering how could I make this so that just can write one short code and depending on if I put [apple], [orange], [mango] it will update the url to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Generate WordPress Shortcodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473011/dynamically-generate-wordpress-shortcodes)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a shortcode called [fruit] and have a parameter called "fruit" so you would only need a single shortcode for all the fruits.

```
function fruit( $atts ) {
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'fruit' => 'apple'
     ), $atts ) );

     if($fruit == "apple") {
         $return = "<a href='http://example.com/fruit/apple/'>Apple</a>";
     } elseif($fruit == "orange") {
         $return = "<a href='http://example.com/fruit/orange/'>Orange</a>";
     }

     return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'fruit', 'fruit' );
```

Then you can call the shortcode [fruit fruit='apple'] or [fruit fruit='orange'].

**EDIT:**

```
function fruit() {
    $label = sanitize_text_field($_GET['slug']);
    $slug  = strtolower($_GET['slug']);


    return "<a href='http://example.com/fruit/" . $slug . "/'>" . $label . "</a>";
}
add_shortcode( 'fruit', 'fruit' );
```

Comment: Thank you, although what I'm trying to avoid is having to do so many of of the if else statements. Fruit isn't my actual custom post type but just used as my example. In my actual custom post type I'm going to have over 100+ posts so is there a way to grab the URL slug and replace it with apple so I don't have to write the line of code every time I add a new post type for all the posts?

Comment: I added an edit, is that more what you are looking for? You may have to edit the `$_GET['slug']` portion.