# Use two shortcodes in 1

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I was wondering if I can use two short codes in 1. I know you can replace variables in shortcodes but what I'm looking for is to use a shortcode say [apple] which will provide a link to the link I give in the shortcode but then if I want an icon next to that link be able to use [apple icon] which than provide a link with the icon to the left of it.

```
add_shortcode('apple', 'apple');
function apple()
{
return '<a href="http://example.com/apple>Apple</a>';
}
```

So is it possible to add icon to where if we add icon to the short code it will also return an image too which I would specify in the shortcode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Generate WordPress Shortcodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473011/dynamically-generate-wordpress-shortcodes)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just give the link a class and add an icon with css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use `attributes`.

```
add_shortcode( 'apple', 'apple' );

function apple( $atts, $content = null )
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'icon' => 'false'), $atts ) );

        if($icon == 'true'){
            $output = '<img src="apple.png" />';
        }

    $output .= '<a href="http://www.example.com">Apple</a>';

    return $output;
}
```

You would then call it like

`[apple icon="true"]`

Here is the documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Comment: Thank you, I figured that was the way I would have to do it. I just wanted to try to make it as simple as possible in terms of just having 'icon' instead of 'icon="true"' since there are multiple authors and it is easier for them to remember just 'icon' since they know nothing about coding.

Comment: Also what does extract mean?

Comment: `extract` takes the array elements and places them into variables http://us3.php.net/extract

Comment: For the closing { of the if statement I'm getting a syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: Thanks for all the help I"ve been using the shortcode and it works great although I'm looking to add one more feature. How would I do another if statement where we would have say image="true" and it displays just what I have for the image and not the icon or the main output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you shouldn't need to create a shortcode in a shortcode.  The shortcode is already executing within your plugin/functions so you should be able to simply invoke your function (or the icon function) directly within your shortcode handler function.  No need to run it through shortcodes again.

If it's not your own shortcode you are looking to call you can call `do_shortcode`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Comment: I'm not looking to use the shortcode outside the editor, i just want to be able to add icon to the shortcode [apple icon] but I'm not sure how to make it work because all the examples I see are something like [apple height="200px"] which is used to replace a variable set in the short code but I don't want to replace anything, i jut want to return the icon image if I have 'icon' added to the shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, it's not necessary to have two shortcodes, just make your shortcode accept arguments:

```
add_shortcode('apple', 'apple');

function apple($args) {
    $default = array('icon' => '');
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $default);

    $content = '';
    if ($args['icon']) {
        $content.= '<img src="icon.png">';
    }

    $content.= '<a href="http://example.com/apple>Apple</a>';

    return $content;
}
```

To use this, you would then enter your shortcode as follows:

```
[apple icon="yes"]
```

If it's simply a "yes/no" for the icon.

Or, you could make it so it loads the icon dynamically based on what you set `icon` equal to, which would require some modifications to the function:

```
function apple($args) {
    $default = array('icon' => '');
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $default);

    $content = '';
    if ($args['icon']) {
        $content.= '<img src="' . $args['icon'] . '">';
    }

    $content.= '<a href="http://example.com/apple>Apple</a>';

    return $content;
}
```

And your shortcode would then look like so:

```
[apple icon="my_icon.png"]
```

(Note, you'd probably need to pass in a fully qualified domain name, like so: `[apple icon="http://example.com/images/my_icon.png"]`)

Comment: Thank you, what would the shortcode look like in this case?